# Remove Tags between other tags

Tags: php, regex

How can I remove the TAG /div between a Tag /bloquote and /figure on the text?
I tried use str_replace, but its not work.

```
$content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam mi augue, molestie sed scelerisque ut, sodales id sapien. Suspendisse potenti. Nam a lacinia orci. Maecenas justo erat, condimentum vel tincidunt id, elementum a turpis. Sed pretium libero a consectetur imperdiet. Duis dignissim at arcu id porta. Phasellus eu nunc elementum, bibendum ex ut, mollis nulla. Cras ullamcorper mollis massa eget ornare. Donec id tortor vitae arcu ullamcorper placerat. <p> <blockquote>Citação etc e tal, modelo teste 123 (Diego)</blockquote> </div> </figure></p> Integer aliquet luctus imperdiet. Nullam tincidunt justo ex, a ultricies elit placerat non. Nullam fringilla dolor vitae metus consequat, ac molestie eros porttitor.";

$content = str_replace('</blockquote>(.*)</figure>','</blockquote></figure>', $content);
```

Comment: You should use an HTML parser, not regex.

Comment: Dig into the docs for [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: The `HTML` is not valid, is this part of the problem or only in the example text?

Comment: Why do you think `str_replace` takes a regex pattern? You need to [use `preg_replace`](https://eval.in/952371).

Comment: Excelent! And, how can i remove the '/p' Tag after the /figure tag? tanks again! :)

Comment: eg. </p> <p><figure> |  I use $content= preg_replace('~</p>.*?<figure>~s','</p><figure>', $content);, but it dosent work. =/

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace not str_replace. Additionally, preg_replace needs a different syntax, proper delimiters and captures the expressions for replacement as "groups".

Try this approach:

```
$content = preg_replace('^(.*)(</blockquote>)(.*)(</div>)(.*)(</figure>)(.*)^s', '$1$2$3$5$6$7', $content);
```

It should be fairly easy to rearrange and adapt to other scenarios and will remove the /div between the /blockquote and /figure. In order each group in parenthesis corresponds to one of the numbered variables in the second argument.  The ^ is a dilemeter that you will need to change if it used anywhere else in the regex. The 's' after the last ^ is the 'dotall' optional modifier that will allow matching over newlines should they show up.  The $3 and $5 variables may contain portions you will want to retain in some situations. Note that the $4 variable was left out of the second argument as it would contain the </div> tag.

Also,

```
$content = preg_replace('^(.*)(</figure>)(.*)(</p>)(.*)^s', '$1$2$3$5', $content);
```

...will remove the /p from after the /figure that you mention in your comments.
Variations on this strategy should work for most similar situations.